# Implement alarm timing in android

Tags: android

i want to implement alarm functionality in my app.so Don't know how to set exact timing for alarm this is my code .when i m trying to set alarm time then it is not triggering at exact time  Please give me any idea......

```
public class Settingscreen extends Activity {
long difference;
int Curenthour;
int currentminute;
int Hourdiffrence;
int Minutedifference;
int MinutedifferencePositive;
int HourdifferencePositive;
CheckBox Checkboxtimeenable;
private int hour;
private int minute;
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
TextView TvSettime;
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB;
Button BtnChangetime;
static final int DATE_PICKER_ID1 = 1111;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
Cursor localCursor = null;
String cursorvalue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settingscreen);

    BtnChangetime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TvSettime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    Checkboxtimeenable = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    TvSettime.setText("18:00");

    BtnChangetime.setEnabled(false);
    try {
        this.sampleDB = openOrCreateDatabase("questionbook", 0, null);

        Settingscreen.this.sampleDB
                .execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists Temp(Time     VARCHAR);");

        localCursor = this.sampleDB.rawQuery("select Time from Temp", null);

        if (localCursor.getCount() > 0) {

            boolean bool = localCursor.moveToFirst();

            if (localCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    TvSettime.setText(localCursor.getString(0));

                    Checkboxtimeenable.setChecked(true);
                    BtnChangetime.setEnabled(true);
                } while (localCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    Checkboxtimeenable
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                int i1;
                int i2;
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Checkboxtimeenable.isChecked()) {
                        BtnChangetime.setEnabled(true);
                        String dtStart = TvSettime.getText().toString();

                        Settingscreen.this.sampleDB
                                .execSQL("INSERT INTO Temp Values ('"
                                        + dtStart + "');");
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "HH:mm");
                        try {
                            Date date = format.parse(dtStart);
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.setTime(date);
                             i1 = cal.getTime().getHours();
                             i2 = cal.getTime().getMinutes();
                            long convertedLong = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                            long currentTimeLong = System
                                    .currentTimeMillis();
                            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                            System.out.println("Current time : "
                                    + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                                    + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                                    + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

                            Curenthour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            currentminute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            Hourdiffrence = Curenthour - i1;
                            Minutedifference = currentminute - i2;
                            MinutedifferencePositive = Math
                                    .abs(Minutedifference);
                            HourdifferencePositive = Math
                                    .abs(Hourdiffrence);
                            System.out.println("Positive number : "
                                    + Math.abs(Hourdiffrence));
                            System.out.println("Positive minute : "
                                    + Math.abs(Minutedifference));
                            System.out.println("Time before 50 minutes : "
                                    + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                                    + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                                    + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

                            String strDiff = String.valueOf(difference);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (Curenthour > i1) {

                            Hourdiffrence = 24 - (Curenthour - i1);
                            Minutedifference = currentminute - i2;
                            MinutedifferencePositive = Math
                                    .abs(Minutedifference);
                            HourdifferencePositive = Math
                                    .abs(Hourdiffrence);

                        } else if (Curenthour < i1) {

                            Hourdiffrence = Curenthour - i1;
                            Minutedifference = currentminute - i2;
                            MinutedifferencePositive = Math
                                    .abs(Minutedifference);
                            HourdifferencePositive = Math
                                    .abs(Hourdiffrence);
                        }

                        if (HourdifferencePositive == 0) {

                            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(
                                    Settingscreen.this, AlarmReciever.class);

                            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                            alarmManager.set(
                                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    System.currentTimeMillis()
                                            + MinutedifferencePositive * 60
                                            * 1000,
                                    PendingIntent
                                            .getBroadcast(
                                                    Settingscreen.this,
                                                    1,
                                                    intentAlarm,
                                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
                            Toast.makeText(Settingscreen.this,
                                    "Alarm Scheduled @" + dtStart,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(
                                    Settingscreen.this, AlarmReciever.class);

                            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                            alarmManager.set(
                                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    System.currentTimeMillis()
                                            + HourdifferencePositive
                                            * MinutedifferencePositive * 60
                                            * 1000,
                                    PendingIntent
                                            .getBroadcast(
                                                    Settingscreen.this,
                                                    1,
                                                    intentAlarm,
                                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
                            Toast.makeText(Settingscreen.this,
                                    "Alarm Scheduled @" + dtStart,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    } else {
                        /*
                         * String where = "Time = 'dtStart'";
                         * 
                         * String[] whereArgs = null; String table_name =
                         * "Temp"; sampleDB.delete(table_name, where,
                         * whereArgs);
                         */
                        sampleDB.execSQL("drop table if exists Temp");
                        Toast.makeText(Settingscreen.this,
                                "Alarm cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(Settingscreen.this,
                                AlarmReciever.class);

                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                System.currentTimeMillis()
                                        + MinutedifferencePositive * 60
                                        * 1000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                        Settingscreen.this, 1, intentAlarm,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
                        BtnChangetime.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }
            });

    BtnChangetime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            long currentTimeLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_PICKER_ID1:

        // open datepicker dialog.
        // set date picker for current date
        // add pickerListener listner to date picker
        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener,
                year, month, day);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+2,cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
        // cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0);
        long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        // d.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(time);
        cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0);
        time = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        return d;

        // return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,
        // day);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

        return new TimePickerDialog(this, myTimeSetListener, hour, minute,
                false);

    default:

    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        // Show selected date

        SimpleDateFormat smpledtf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyy");
    }
};
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener myTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        String time = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(minute);
        TvSettime.setText(time);

        Settingscreen.this.sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Temp Values ('"
                + time + "');");
        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(Settingscreen.this,
                AlarmReciever.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + MinutedifferencePositive * 60
                        * 1000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        Settingscreen.this, 1, intentAlarm,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
        String dtStart = TvSettime.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(dtStart);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            i1 = cal.getTime().getHours();
            System.out.println("alarm hour :"+ i1);
             i2 = cal.getTime().getMinutes();
            long convertedLong = cal.getTimeInMillis();
            long currentTimeLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

            System.out.println("Current time : "
                    + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                    + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                    + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

            /*
             * now.add(Calendar.MINUTE,i2);
             * 
             * System.out.println("New time after adding 20 minutes : " +
             * now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" +
             * now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
             */

            // now = Calendar.getInstance();
            // now.add(Calendar.HOUR, -i1);
            Curenthour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            System.out.println("current hour :"+ Curenthour);
            currentminute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            Hourdiffrence = Curenthour - i1;
            Minutedifference = currentminute - i2;
            MinutedifferencePositive = Math.abs(Minutedifference);
            HourdifferencePositive = Math.abs(Hourdiffrence);
            System.out.println("Positive number : "
                    + Math.abs(Hourdiffrence));
            System.out.println("Positive minute : "
                    + Math.abs(Minutedifference));
            System.out.println("Time before 50 minutes : "
                    + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                    + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                    + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

            String strDiff = String.valueOf(difference);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (i1 > Curenthour) {

            Hourdiffrence = 24 - (Curenthour - i1);
            Minutedifference = currentminute - i2;
            MinutedifferencePositive = Math
                    .abs(Minutedifference);
            HourdifferencePositive = Math
                    .abs(Hourdiffrence);

        } else if (Curenthour > i1) {

            Hourdiffrence = Curenthour - i1;
            Minutedifference = currentminute - i2;
            MinutedifferencePositive = Math
                    .abs(Minutedifference);
            HourdifferencePositive = Math
                    .abs(Hourdiffrence);
        }
        if (HourdifferencePositive == 0) {

            Intent intentAlarm2 = new Intent(Settingscreen.this,
                    AlarmReciever.class);

            AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + MinutedifferencePositive
                            * 60 * 1000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            Settingscreen.this, 1, intentAlarm,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            Toast.makeText(Settingscreen.this,
                    "Alarm Scheduled @" + dtStart, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Intent intentAlarm2 = new Intent(Settingscreen.this,
                    AlarmReciever.class);

            AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager
                    .set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            System.currentTimeMillis()
                                    + HourdifferencePositive
                                    * MinutedifferencePositive * 60 * 1000,
                            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Settingscreen.this,
                                    1, intentAlarm,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            Toast.makeText(Settingscreen.this,
                    "Alarm Scheduled @" + dtStart, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.